# Serverless : "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined",

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverless-framework

I'm getting started trying to write a lambda function with node and puppeteer. I'm using the serverless framework.

In my handler.js:

```
exports.detail = async (event, context) => {
  console.log(event);

  let id = event.pathParameters.id || 1;
  console.log(id);
```

I've been trying to pass in an id parameter with the event parameter, but if its not set I want the value to be set to 1 . But when I try:

```
$ sls invoke local -f detail 

{
"errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined",
"errorType": "TypeError",
"stackTrace": [
    "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined",
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: checkout this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52251075/how-to-pass-parameters-to-serverless-invoke-local

Comment: as you not passing prams  you can update this line to  event.pathParameters.id ->  (event && event.pathParameters && event.pathParameters.id)?event.pathParameters.id:1

Comment: Thank you, but why doesn't "  let id = event.pathParameters.id || 1;" work?

Comment: it's simply you are checking if event object has pathParameters and then checking pathParameters has id property only then access access  event.pathParameters.id , else return 1 , if your event.pathParameters  is empty / undefined as you didn't pass it , pathParameters  property does not exists  , so javascript is throwing error , it's not right way to access so , we have added a condition to be sure id exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.pathParameters.id` is failing because `event.pathParameters` is undefined. The error message is telling you that `undefined` has no property called `id`.

Try:

`let id = event.pathParameters ? event.pathParameters.id : 1;`

instead

Comment: close, but let id = (event && event.pathParameters && event.pathParameters.id)?event.pathParameters.id:1 - worked in my case ...