# Why i get undefined in console?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am new to aws and serverless .I don't know why i get undefined in the variable called - first:
When i execute the function the command

```
sls invoke local -f hello -d '{"first":2}'
```

The object

```
{
   "first":2
}
```

is send to the serverless function.And it is in the response in the event property.
Why when i try to get the value of event.first i get undefined?

```
'use strict'

module.exports.hello = (event, context, callback) => {
  const first = event.first;
  console.log("**", first);
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      event: event
    }),
  };
  callback(null, response);
}
```

When i try event,first i need to get only the number in this case 2,but i get undefined

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910939/how-to-get-json-key-and-value-in-javascript

Comment: what is the response value? - so you can check the value of event

Comment: When i try event,first i need to get only the number in this case 2,but i get undefined

Comment: Print out the `event` object and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52251075/how-to-pass-parameters-to-serverless-invoke-local

Comment: I have tried the same and it is working fine and the logs are coming as "2" as expected