# How invoke serverless function locally passing `body` params and retrieve those params?

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, lambda, serverless

I am trying to test a lambda function locally, using serverless framework. This function is attached to a POST endpoint, defined as:

```yaml
createCat:
  handler: app/handler.createCat
  events:
    - http:
        path: cats/
        method: post
```

I invoke the function locally a according to [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52777428/2076973):

```bash
# Command line
serverless invoke local --function createCat --path local-invoke/createCat.json --stage local

# createCat.json
{
  "body": {
    "name": "Cat cat blue",
    "age": 4,
    "color": "blue"
  }
}
```

I am trying to parse the body and get the items like it is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648467/getting-json-body-in-aws-lambda-via-api-gateway), but it does not work:

```js
import { Context } from 'aws-lambda';

const createCat = async (event: any, context?: Context) => {
  try{
  const data  = JSON.parse(event.body)

  let name = data?.name
  let age = Number(data?.age)
  let color = data?.color

  return {
    statusCode: 500,
    message: data
  }
  }
  catch(error) {
  return {
    statusCode: 500,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: getMessageFromError(error)
    })
  }
  } 
}
```

I am getting this output, instead of the parsed body:

```bash
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "body": "{\"message\":\"Unexpected token l in JSON at position 0\"}"
}
```

[Serverless documentation on local invoke](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/invoke#invoke-local) does not touch on how to pass/retrieve body params either.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When invoking the deployed lambda, `event.body` is a **scaped JSON string**. However, when invoking locally with `serverless invoke local`, it is an **object literal** in javascript, and the parsing error happens since it is trying to parse this object literal.

I wrote a helper function to help cover both cases seamlessly:

```js
// types.ts
export interface ParsedEvent {
  body: any | undefined,
  pathParameters: any | undefined
}

// util.ts
import { ParsedEvent } from "./types"

export const parseEvent = (event: any) : ParsedEvent => {
  let parsedEvent : ParsedEvent = {
    body: undefined,
    pathParameters: undefined
  }

  parsedEvent.pathParameters = event?.pathParameters

  // Parse body if it is stringified JSON
  if(typeof event?.body === 'string' )
  {   
    parsedEvent.body = JSON.parse(event?.body)
  } else {
    parsedEvent.body = event?.body
  }

  return parsedEvent
}
```

and use it as:

```js
import { Context } from 'aws-lambda';
import { parseEvent } from './util.js';

const createCat = async (event: any, context?: Context) => {
  let parsedEvent = parseEvent(event)
  
  // body params
  let name = parsedEvent.body?.name
  let age = parsedEvent.body?.age
  
  // path params
  let id = parsedEvent.pathParameters?.id
}
```